# Can a spanning tree contain a self loop?

Tags: graph, adjacency-matrix, spanning-tree

I am referring to explanation of spanning tree given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpanningTree.html).

I want to know can a spanning tree contain self loop? I.e. edge from one vertex to itself? I guess, no; because then for that loop there are two paths to reach that node. one direct and one including loop, but I want to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)) article about trees, a tree is required to be cycle-free, which consequentially also holds for a [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree).